# Move specific word to beginning of cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, text, excel-formula, move

I have large spreadsheet that contains entries like:

```
Alabama Men's Sport Bracelet Team Color Dial
```

For each one I need to move the word `Men's` to the front of the text in the cell. Many of the cells contain the word `Ladies` rather than `Men's` but require the same operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A (marginally) shorter version than @rwilson's, but very similar:

```
=IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Men's",A1),"Men's "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Men's ","")),IFERROR(IF(SEARCH("Ladies",A1),"Ladies "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Ladies ","")),A1))
```

Comment: This formula works a little better because it doesn't require me to use TRIM to remove extra spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The formula assumes the text is in cell A1 and it searches for the exact string "Men's" or "Ladies":

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Men's",A1)),"Men's "&" "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Men's",""), IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Ladies",A1)),"Ladies "&" "&SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Ladies",""),A1))
```